# Smallest possible object made of atoms that is spherical to a given degree

Tags: mass, atoms

I recently saw a video, [World's Roundest Object](http://youtu.be/ZMByI4s-D-Y), which discussed a sphere made of silicon-28. The researcher in the video stated, if the object was scaled to the size of the Earth, the highest and lowest points would only differ by 14 meters in height.

**How small can an object be while still being round?** If we need to define *roundness*, lets compare it to the silicon-28 sphere when both objects are scaled to the size of the Earth.

A single atom is boring, so lets exclude that. Two atoms doesn't seem round. Maybe 16? 300? Which atom(s)?

Comment: An electron?  I don't see why you couldn't, in theory, choose pretty much any set of atoms and make something just as round with fewer.  Far more atoms were used in the silicon-28 spheres than actually needed since they were mechanically polished.

Comment: Nothing is actually perfectly round you know.

Comment: @ja72 "compare it to the silicon-28 sphere when both objects are scaled"

Comment: I edited the title of this question to make clear that it is limited to spheres made of atoms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Buckminsterfullerene (C-60)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene) is about as close as you could get to spherical with 60 atoms.

Earth's radius is 6,371,000 meters and Buckminsterfullerene's radius is 3.5 nanomoeters (nm).  A carbon atom's radius is about 0.07nm (which I would approximate as the degree of deviation from roundness of Buckminsterfullerene).  Therefore, Buckminsterfullerene deviates from spherical to a much greater degree than the silicon sphere.

6,371,000m is about 500,000 X 14m.  500,000 X 0.07nm = 35 micrometers.

So I would estimate 35 micrometers to be the smallest object made of atoms that one could make and still have the smoothness of the silicon ball.